# Click Functionality doesn't work properly in mobile devices

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, css, shopify

We are facing an issue in our shopify website in mobile devices. On clicking a category, it opens and child menu items dropped down. But it doesn't get closed on clicking back. Only it gets closed, when we click on another category menu.

Could anyone help here.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any example? Maybe somewhere we can see the site in action? *Quick suggestion:* You could try closing the menu with javascript manually when clicking 'back'.

Comment: Here is the site : www.animalcollectibles.com. Its the sidebar menu (Categories Menu) on home page. Hover Functionality works perfectly fine in Desktops. But on mobile devices click feature shows inconsistency while opening/closing the category items. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Its better to show code you are trying.

Main problem is OnClick Event does not register on mobile devices that
is because you don't click on anything you generally tap on menu. So
it will be better if you add mobile event along with it. like you can
use touchstart event as give in code below

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('ul li').on('click touchstart', function() {

    // Show Menu Item

    });
});
```

**Another Alternative Option**

you can also detect touch devices and manipulate things -

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
    /* Detect Mobile Device As Below */
    if(is_touch_device()) {  
        // Code Here to handle for Mobile
    }
});
```

Comment: Here is the site : www.animalcollectibles.com. Its the sidebar menu (Categories Menu) on home page. Hover Functionality works perfectly fine in Desktops. But on mobile devices click feature shows inconsistency while opening/closing the category items. What could be the reason and how could it be resolved ? Thanks.